Method for plotting hex code numbers as a dependent variable
I am trying to create a data visualization showing the effects of moisture and temperature on plant stem colors, but the plant stem colors are unique hex codes taken from photographs. I had planned to create a correlation plot or heat map to capture this, but I'm not sure how to handle the hexcodes. I've gone through and also just calculated the red values out of the hex codes, but again, I'm not sure how to translate this into a figure in R. Here is a bit of my data that reflects the problem:
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(light = c(rep("sun",2),rep("shade",2),rep("mid",2)),
             moisture = c(8,2,4,5,6,7),
             temp = c(85,67,44,55,68,56),
             stem_color = c("#46383d", "#370f1c", "#61374e", "#506843","#688641","#5f5c4d"),
             red = c(70,55,97,80,104,95)))

df1$moisture <- as.numeric(df1$moisture)
df1$temp <- as.numeric(df1$temp)
df1$red <- as.numeric(df1$red)


Hi ElizaBeso000. When creating the df1 data frame, you don't need to use cbind(). Can you please edit this question to show more of what you're trying to achieve, even if the final plot isn't there yet? If the idea is to show how stem_color changes with moisture and temp, I'd try a scatterplot with points colored by stem_color.

Here is a geom_tile() example showing how to handle the hex codes in relation to your data. I have modified your df1 code as cbind() is not necessary and causes the numeric variables to become character vectors. This way, no need to correct them after.
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(light = rep(c("sun", "shade", "mid"), each = 2),
                  moisture = c(8,2,4,5,6,7),
                  temp = c(85,67,44,55,68,56),
                  stem_color = c("#46383d", "#370f1c", "#61374e", "#506843","#688641","#5f5c4d"),
                  red = c(70,55,97,80,104,95))

ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = df1, aes(x = moisture, y = temp, fill = stem_color)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = df1$stem_color,
                    labels = df1$light)


